# kivy demo examples not working

Tags: android, kivy

I have installed kivy as per docs and created a apk using command

```
./build.py --dir /home/home/Downloads/Kivy-1.7.2/examples/demo/touchtracer     --package org.demo.touchtracer     --name "Kivy Touchtracer" --version 1.1.0 debug installd
```

this created and installed apk in my emulator on ubuntu. but, clicking on app just blink screen once and no output can be seen.

can anyone let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you emulating a recent version (4.0 or after I think), and is hardware acceleration enabled in the virtual machine? Also, what happens if you install a known working apk, such as Flat Jewels from the play store?

Comment: i am using older version 2.2 and how to chk hardware acceleration?

Comment: You need to use a newer version. Older version don't even support hardware acceleration, but it is vital to kivy.

Comment: ok i wl chk, and can you know why this error come and how to solve it? subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: That's a fairly generic build failure message at the ant stage. If this is your problem, could you post a full build failure log?

Comment: yes. http://pastebin.com/kJARWZW6

Comment: Could you set log_level to 2 in the buildozer.spec file and try again. This will print a lot more debug information. Also, you could put it in a different question since this one isn't really appropriate.

Comment: i have added and these are 2 logs.1. http://pastebin.com/270Sbz9i and 2. http://pastebin.com/egPi913R

Comment: please let me know how can i solve this? there is nothing i found on net

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cd /home/home/Downloads/Kivy-1.7.2/examples/demo/touchtracer

python main.py
```

That worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

you shoud enable Hardware accelarator on emulator  (use HOST GPU)

for this method does'nt work on API 14 (it'll show you black screen on emulator , just it)
but it works perfectly on API 17 ,18 , 19